# jquery drag and drop sortable between different div and div class

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I want to drag a div of left panel and drop it to right panel using jquery sortable (interface.js).. i tried, but can't solve...

Code is given below

```
$(document).ready(
            function () 
            {
                $('div#block-selector').Sortable(
                    {
                        accept: 'new-component',
                        helperclass: 'sortHelper',
                        activeclass :   'sortableactive',
                        hoverclass :    'sortablehover',
                        handle: 'span',
                        tolerance: 'pointer',
                        connectWith: '#droppableArea',
                        containment: 'div#droppableArea',
                        onChange : function(ser)
                        {

                        },
                        onStart : function()
                        {
                            $.iAutoscroller.start(this, document.getElementsByTagName('body'));
                        },
                        onStop : function()
                        {

                            $.iAutoscroller.stop();
                        }
                    }
                );
            }

        );
```

div#block-selector is a div of left panel and drop it to div#droppableArea of right panel.. but not working .. pls help meeeeeee

regardz

wahid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you use sortable? I think JQuery UI Droppable is working fine for your purpose ( http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#photo-manager )